# Delete expired posts after a number of days after they expired

Tags: functions, automation

I use the below code to delete custom posts with status 'expired' (thanks to [Jamie Keefer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27386129/1354580)). Posts are set as 'expired' by a 3rd party plugin. Users have only a frontend access to their posts (adverts).

My question is: **how to delete them after a number of days after they expired if post authors don't republish them?** Also, I will appreciate any suggestions about how to improve this code.

```
// expired_post_delete hook fires when the Cron is executed
add_action( 'expired_post_delete', 'delete_expired_posts' );

// This function will run once the 'expired_post_delete' is called
function delete_expired_posts() {

    $todays_date = current_time('mysql');

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'advert',
        'post_status' => 'expired',
        'posts_per_page' => -1
    );

    $posts = new WP_Query( $args );

    // The Loop
    if ( $posts->have_posts() ) {

        while ( $posts->have_posts() ) {
            $posts->the_post();
            wp_delete_post(get_the_ID());
        }

    } else {
            // no posts found
    }

    /* Restore original Post Data */
    wp_reset_postdata();
}

// Add function to register event to WordPress init
add_action( 'init', 'register_daily_post_delete_event');

// Function which will register the event
function register_daily_post_delete_event() {
    // Make sure this event hasn't been scheduled
    if( !wp_next_scheduled( 'expired_post_delete' ) ) {
        // Schedule the event
        wp_schedule_event( time(), 'daily', 'expired_post_delete' );
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

This is how posts are set as 'expired':

```
add_action( 'adverts_event_expire_ads', 'adverts_event_expire_ads' );

/**
 * Expires ads
 * 
 * Function finds Adverts that already expired (value in _expiration_date
 * meta field is lower then current timestamp) and changes their status to 'expired'.
 * 
 * @since 0.1
 * @return void
 */
function adverts_event_expire_ads() {

    // find adverts with status 'publish' which exceeded expiration date
    // (_expiration_date is a timestamp)
    $posts = new WP_Query( array( 
        "post_type" => "advert",
        "post_status" => "publish",
        "meta_query" => array(
            array(
                "key" => "_expiration_date",
                "value" => current_time( 'timestamp' ),
                "compare" => "<="
            )
        )
    ) );


    if( $posts->post_count ) {
        foreach($posts->posts as $post) {
            // change post status to expired.
            $update = wp_update_post( array( 
                "ID" => $post->ID,
                "post_status" => "expired"
            ) );
        } // endforeach
    } // endif

}
```

Comment: Don' your code work or are you just looking to do it better. There are definite bugs in your code and it is also really expensive. There are plenty room for improvement here

Comment: @pieter-goosen It seems to work. I tested it once, one expired post was deleted, but I am not sure if this was my code, as an other plugin with a similar function was active at that moment. I deactivated that plugin (I don't like it, too big) and now I am waiting to see if the second one will be deleted (changed the `wp_schedule_event()` to `hourly`). And sure, I want also to improve this code, but I am not the recommended expert for this type of work :).

Comment: @pieter-goosen Checked today, the second expired post was not deleted :(.

Comment: wp-cron jobs aren't very reliable, someone needs to be logged in for a wp-cron job to execute. It does not work uatomatically like server crons. I see that the answer from @birgire did not solve your issue. You should file an edit and explain how the expired post status are set,

Comment: Also, does the plugin store any extra meta data when the post stauts are set to `expired`. How do you know that a post was set to `expired` x days ago. I need to know that in order to formulate a solution

Comment: I have updated the question. Let me know if you need to know something else.

Comment: About wp-cron jobs: because I am the only user of the system and I was disconnected for a while, this is why my code doesn't worked? In this case, in a system with multiple active users the wp-cron jobs must be more productive?

Comment: Note, the function that sets the post status is also very expensive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

WP Cron jobs are not reliable as it needs someone to visit the site at the time the event should fire. If you need precise timing, you should use server cron jobs.

Anyways, lets look at your code and what is wrong and we can fix it

- `wp` is a better hook to use to hook your scheduled event, this is the earliest that postdata available. `init` is way to early. I probably think for safety, you can also try the `template_redirect` hook.
- Your code are very very expensive to run which unnecessarily wastes server resources. We need to look at the following:

  - We do not need any postdata except the post ID. Any other postdata are useless, and querying it waste a lot of resources. On large sites, this can actually lead to fatal errors due to timing out
  - We only need to query posts which has expired and the expiry date has reached a certain timeframe.

Lets put everything in code: (***NOTE:*** This all untested, I have also copied and pasted some of your code, so I might have missed something, and also, the code requires PHP 5.4+)

```
function get_exired_posts_to_delete()
{
    /**
     * If you need posts that expired more than a week ago, we would need to
     * get the unix time stamp of the day a week ago. You can adjust the relative 
     * date and time formats as needed. 
     * @see http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php
     * @see http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php
     */
    // As example, we need to get posts that has expired more than 7days ago
    $past = strtotime( "- 1 week" );

    // Set our query arguments
    $args = [
        'fields'         => 'ids', // Only get post ID's to improve performance
        'post_type'      => 'advert',
        'post_status'    => 'expired',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'meta_query'     => [
            [
                'key'     => '_expiration_date',
                'value'   => $past,
                'compare' => '<='
            ]
        ]
    ];
    $q = get_posts( $args );

    // Check if we have posts to delete, if not, return false
    if ( !$q )
        return false;

    // OK, we have posts to delete, lets delete them
    foreach ( $q as $id )
        wp_delete_post( $id );
}
```

Now we can create our custom hook to hook our function

```
// expired_post_delete hook fires when the Cron is executed
add_action( 'expired_post_delete', 'get_exired_posts_to_delete' );
```

Lastly, schedule our event

```
// Add function to register event to wp
add_action( 'wp', 'register_daily_post_delete_event');
function register_daily_post_delete_event() {
    // Make sure this event hasn't been scheduled
    if( !wp_next_scheduled( 'expired_post_delete' ) ) {
        // Schedule the event
        wp_schedule_event( time(), 'daily', 'expired_post_delete' );
    }
}
```

This should about do it, just remember to set the correct time frame inside the function

Comment: Pieter, thank you very much! I teste the code and it works very well. I only changed the `wp_delete_post( $id );` to `wp_trash_post( $id );` because the first deletes expired posts permanently and the second just trash them, so post authors will have a last chance to restore an important post (with admin help). Thanks again! P.S. I will try to improve myself the expensive function that sets the post status.

Comment: Glad it worked as expected. As always, my code can be extented and modified to suite your exact needs. Enjoy ;-)

Comment: Pieter, I do not understand why the `'fields' => 'ids'` is needed, without it the code will not work? The other arguments are not enough?

Comment: This is quite an extensive question which will be better if asked as a new question. What do you men by *The other arguments re not enough*

Comment: I mean the remaining arguments from the query arguments (so, excluding the `'fields' => 'ids'`). About the first part of my last question, maybe I will ask a new question. Thanks!

Comment: `'fields' => 'ids'` are there for performance. We really only need the post ID's from the query as our delete/trash function only requires a post ID. When set, only an array of post ID's are returned, and not an array of post **objects** as per default. Setting `fields` to `ids` makes your query hundreds of times faster. You can still add any argument you desire to your query arguments, everything still works the same, exept the loop. But as I say, to completely answer this, you need to ask a new question because a proper explanation cnnot be done in comments ;-)

Answer (score 3):

### The native trash bin

It sounds like you're implementing your own version of the WordPress ***trash*** system.

If you *trash* a post, the native way, it will get the `trash` post status and will be automatically deleted (permanently) after 30 days. You can change that in your `wp-config.php` file with:

```
define( 'EMPTY_TRASH_DAYS', 10 );
```

for e.g. 10 days.

You can then trash your post with [`wp_trash_post( $post_id )`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_trash_post) instead of creating your own custom `expire` post status.

This way you let the system work **with you** ;-)

For more info check the [*trash status*](https://codex.wordpress.org/Trash_status) in the Codex.

Comment: Posts (CPT 'adverts') are marked as 'expired' by a plugin, I just want to delete them a few days after 'expiring' if post authors don't republish them. I can't *trash* these posts because post authors have access only to their published or expired posts on the frontend, not to the backend (and to trashed posts).

Comment: Your question should contain this new information (3rd party plugin, frontend access only, republish) so please update it. ps: It should be possible via filter to override the post status from expire to trash.