# wp_delete_post deletes all posts instead of just expired ones

Tags: php, wp-query

I am trying to set up a cron job which deletes posts which have past their expiry date (i.e expiry date < today's date). I have a meta box on the custom post type which adds an expiry date to the post.

I have set up the cron job to trigger the wp_delete_post every hour. However, rather than deleted only the posts which have passed the expiry date, it deletes ALL the posts in the custom post type.

Can anyone see where the problem is? Thanks

```
add_action( 'wp', 'delete_expired_adverts_daily' );
function delete_expired_adverts_daily() {
    if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'delete_expired_adverts' ) ) {
        wp_schedule_event( time(), 'hourly', 'delete_expired_adverts');
    }
}
add_action( 'delete_expired_adverts', 'delete_expired_adverts_callback' );

function delete_expired_adverts_callback() {
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'advert',
        'posts_per_page' => -1
    );

    $query_ads = new WP_Query($args);
    if ($query_ads->have_posts()):
        while($query_ads->have_posts()): $query_ads->the_post();    

            $expiry_date = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'expires', true);
            $today = date('d-m-Y');

            $today_split = strtotime($today);
            $expiry_split = strtotime($expiry_date);

            if ($expiry_split < $today_split) {
                wp_delete_post(get_the_ID());
                //Use wp_delete_post(get_the_ID(),true) to delete the post from the trash too.                  
            }

        endwhile;
    endif;
}
```

Comment: Only query deleted posts, why are you querying all posts. also, in what format is your date saved in your custom field. If it is not unix time stamp or `Ymd`, you are pretty screwed here querying only expired posts. This is also most probably the reason why everything backfires because I see you use `dmY` style dates. All formats should match, and dates in custom fields should be stored in `Ymd` format or unix timestamp

Comment: The date is converted to unix timestamp using `strtotime` so that's not the issue (I know because I have echoed it to check). But I guess what you're saying is the expiry date should be queried when the $args array is set up?

Comment: Converting the date once the post is returned should not be big issue, the big issue is how the format is stored in db. Your code is extremely expensive with huge unnecessary overheads. Even if you get your dates sorted inside the loop, it is still a huge expensive operation to run.

Comment: Ok, I can fix that pretty easily and store it in the db as unix time. However, that doesn't fix my problem of all the posts being deleted.

Comment: It does, if your date is correctly stored in unix or in `Ymd` format, then you can use a meta_query and only query expired posts.

Comment: [Here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/209173/31545) is some inspiration

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look and let you know how I get on ;-)

Comment: I've hit a problem. I'm using jquery datepicker to enter the value into the db. The dateFormat : '@' value generated by datepicker is in milliseconds, not the same as the unix timestamp (so I get extra 000 on the end of the value). When I try to convert this back to a date is comes out incorrect.

Comment: You should update your question with that info. Also post an example of the exact format the date is saved in

Comment: I have created a new question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34768813/jquery-datepicker-change-dateformat-to-unis-timestamp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anyone else needs the code, this is how I solved it. @pieter-goosen was right, I did need to query the correct posts, but the real trick was matching the date format from the jquery datepicker when running the post query. Check the date formats below, jquery is 'yy-mm-dd', and the php equivalent is 'Y-m-d'.

So the js for the datepicker was:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('.ExDate').datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
        });
    });
</script>
```

And the cron function was:

```
add_action( 'wp', 'delete_expired_adverts_daily' );
function delete_expired_adverts_daily() {
    if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'delete_expired_adverts' ) ) {
        wp_schedule_event( time(), 'daily', 'delete_expired_adverts');
    }
}
add_action( 'delete_expired_adverts', 'delete_expired_adverts_callback' );

function delete_expired_adverts_callback() {

    $args = array (
                'post_type'    => 'advert',
                'meta_key'     => 'expires',
                'meta_value'   => date('Y-m-d'),
                'meta_compare' => '<=',
            );

    $query_ads = new WP_Query($args);
    if ($query_ads->have_posts()):
        while($query_ads->have_posts()): $query_ads->the_post();    

            wp_delete_post(get_the_ID(), true);

        endwhile;
    endif;
}
```

Comment: This will fail. You are going to get mismatched posts somewhere and then delete wrong posts. There is no way custom fields can correctly match dates if it is not `Y-m-d` or unix,  `d-m-Y` will fail unfortunately ;-)

Comment: It works fine. The date is always added to the db in the same format, d-m-Y

Comment: It works fine for certain dates, but it will fail. Custom fields matches literally. I will look, I have answered something like this where I have explained this well ;-)

Comment: OK thanks. I haven't had a problem with it so far. In my circumstance, I am always adding the expiry date as a predefined format using the jquery date picker.

Comment: *I am always adding the expiry date as a predefined format*, it does not matter, in a custom field `01-01-2015` will be a newer date than `02-02-2016`, and `02-02-2016` will be an older date than `01-01-2015`. You can test that yourself. This is where your code will fail and you will delete a wrong post. I can warn you against this and beg you to not use `d-m_Y` but rather `Y-m-d`, but if you do not want to listen, it is your problem. You will come running back later asking **WHY** is the wrong posts deleted

Comment: Sorry Pieter, I misunderstood your comment. I thought you meant I should always use a unix timestamp rather than date format, and in fact you are suggesting I use YEAR first in the date format, correct?

Comment: That is correct yes, if you use normal dates, year must be first, then month, then day, not day, month year. I know many countries uses many types of formats, but custom fields **require** year month day for searching and sorting purposes. Unix is an alternative which you can also use, but you do not need to use it, as long as your date is year, month day ;-)

Comment: Got it, thanks! I have updated the answer accordingly.