# function post to trash problem

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, functions

I know that are some questions like mine BUT I did not find solution for my problem!

I try to create for client an auto post expire for custom post type called “event” that when a new post is created, then after a some time ( after 30 minutes or 2 days)  the post must to go to trash.

I  found a code in this post “ [Delete expired posts after a number of days after they expired](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/209046/delete-expired-posts-after-a-number-of-days-after-they-expired) ”

But does not work on me.

Any help is appreciated

Here is the code that I use and not working :

```
function get_exired_posts_to_delete()
{
    
    $past = strtotime( "- 30 minute" );

    // Set our query arguments
    $args = [
        'fields'         => 'ids', // Only get post ID's to improve performance
        'post_type'      => 'event',
        'post_status'    => 'expired',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'meta_query'     => [
            [
                'key'     => '',
                'value'   => $past,
                'compare' => '<='
            ]
        ]
    ];
    $q = get_posts( $args );

    // Check if we have posts to delete, if not, return false
    if ( !$q )
        return false;

    // OK, we have posts to delete, lets delete them
    foreach ( $q as $id )
        wp_trash_post( $id );
}

// expired_post_delete hook fires when the Cron is executed
add_action( 'expired_post_delete', 'get_exired_posts_to_delete' );

// Add function to register event to wp
add_action( 'wp', 'register_daily_post_delete_event');
function register_daily_post_delete_event() {
    // Make sure this event hasn't been scheduled
    if( !wp_next_scheduled( 'expired_post_delete' ) ) {
        // Schedule the event
        wp_schedule_event( time(), 'daily', 'expired_post_delete' );
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Hello and I am very grateful for help me guys.

Cron event is active. Also I change the post status from expire to publish and I remove the 'key'     => '' Now the problem is that if I run this “updated function” it move all posts to trash!
AND it DOES NOT move the post(s) that are in 2 days old .

for example I have two posts: event1 and event2.
the post with name “event1” is created at “05-12-2020 ” and the post with name “event2” is created at “08-12-2020 ”.
If the function is set with  `$past = strtotime( "- 2 days " );` then the function must move the post with name “event1” in to trash.

Any ideas;

```
function get_exired_posts_to_delete()
{

    $past = strtotime( "- 2 days " );

    // Set our query arguments
    $args = [
        'fields'         => 'ids', // Only get post ID's to improve performance
        'post_type'      => 'event',
        'post_status'    => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'meta_query'     => [
                'value'   => $past,
                'compare' => '<='
      ]
    
    ];
    $q = get_posts( $args );

    // Check if we have posts to delete, if not, return false
    if ( !$q )
        return false;

    // OK, we have posts to delete, lets delete them
    foreach ( $q as $id )
        wp_trash_post( $id );
}

// expired_post_delete hook fires when the Cron is executed
add_action( 'expired_post_delete', 'get_exired_posts_to_delete' );

// Add function to register event to wp
add_action( 'wp', 'register_daily_post_delete_event');
function register_daily_post_delete_event() {
    // Make sure this event hasn't been scheduled
    if( !wp_next_scheduled( 'expired_post_delete' ) ) {
        // Schedule the event
        wp_schedule_event( time(), 'hourly', 'expired_post_delete' );
    }
}
```

Comment: How ae you debugging this? does Cron run, does it find your action - does the get_posts return any results - you need to locate the point at which things breaks down in order to resolve any problems.

Comment: Why is your meta key blank? I see your post status is set to expired, that isn't a valid post status in standard WP, how is that being set? Have you confirmed your cron job runs?

Comment: i have update my "question" !